# Inverse version of stackexchange - aggregated place to ask questions

Tags: feature-request, questions

Stackoverflow is fragmenting into smaller sites, which is great since these sites have a very good signal to noise ratio.

But what I'm starting to feel is missing is sort of an aggregation site, from which these question would be sorted onto other (more specific) sites. Or is stackoverflow meant to serve this purpose?

Comment: Related (in my mind at least), is there a way to search for a question across all stack exchange sites?

Comment: @Jerry Go to stackexchange and search.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wrapper around Stack Exchange properties?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85484/wrapper-around-stack-exchange-properties)

Comment: actually this is slightly diff from that question in the sense that...now the **programming/software** questions are getting newer places instead of SO. Like discussions on software development used to be on SO, (I've seen older questions) but now they're on programmers, even DBA questions I guess will move soon to a newer site. Although I don't know if this is such a bad thing since now we have a more focused audience for those questions.

Answer (score 3):

> ...from which these question would be sorted onto other (more specific) sites.  Or is stackoverflow meant to serve this purpose?

No!  *You* are expected to find the site your question will be most suited to.  Please read the site-specific FAQ before posting.

Comment: Interesting. The problem is that stackoverflow is currently being used as a dump everything site.